# Is it possible to put mathematical text in Excel?

Tags: excel, math, text

[image]

I would like to put such a mathematical sentence (in the latex format of course) into an Excel 2016 cell, like a text. Is it possible? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, you could look at `HELP` for something like `Insert Equation`

Comment: Try Insert -> Equation. You can format the resulting text box to include regular text passages as well. It's not quite the same as putting it in a single cell, but good enough for presentation purposes. For more extensive math it's not a very pleasant way to work.

Comment: I know that I can use "Insert equation". 
But the problem is that it will not be inserted in a cell. 
It will be like an additional layer on my excel sheet.
I suppose in this case I should stick to MS WORD.

Comment: Excel has only very limited support for formatting text in cells, and doesn't support compound formatting, so text-based mathematics in a cell is essentially impossible. Even something as simple as a sub- and superscript can only be applied to the cell as a whole.

Comment: If you just want superscripts and subscripts instead of any mathematical expressions then you can alternatively use [the Unicode characters for them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim s As String
    Dim A2 As Range
    Set A2 = Range("A2")
    s = "In the sequence 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ... each term is a perfect square.  The first term is is 12, the second term is 22, and so on.  A general formula for the nth term of the sequence is un=n2."
    A2 = s
    A2.Characters(Start:=92, Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
    A2.Characters(Start:=115, Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
    A2.Characters(Start:=158, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle = "Italic"
    A2.Characters(Start:=185, Length:=1).Font.Subscript = True
    A2.Characters(Start:=188, Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True

End Sub
```

[image]

The `Character` formatting follows VBA standards rather than latex or html tagging.

Comment: You got the formatting of "*n*th" wrong, which I suppose is a good illustration of why you really don't want to have to do this. Nevertheless, it's technically a solution...

Comment: Thank You very much for this tip. 

I'm writing a glossary of mathematical terms. The formatting of "nth" is not mine as it comes from the IB manual by OXFORD UNIVERSITY PRESS.

And I will have plenty of such cases with mathematical writing. If I were to write VBA code for each cell then it would not make sense. This is why I will stick to WORD. 

Although it is a pity because I like Excel very much.